# Steal my infix, I am a type of python

Tags: riddle, word

It is 5 characters.

Remove one, my meaning does not change.
Remove two, I am a cat.
Remove all of them, I am a empty spot.
Remove all but one, I am a number.
Steal my infix, I am a type of python.

Comment: completely off the wall question, but are you sure you are a cat and not a dog?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> BOMBA

Remove one, my meaning does not change.

> BOMBA is the Spanish for BOMB (one letter removed)

Remove two, I am a cat.

> [BOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Street_Cat_Named_Bob_(film))

Remove all of them, I am a empty spot.

> Not sure about this, surely if you remove all the letters from a word it becomes empty - possibly a reference to being cleared by a bomb.

Remove all but one, I am a number.

> M (Roman numeral for 1000)

Steal my infix, I am a type of python.

> [BOA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boa)

Comment: I had this exact answer, and for whatever reason put it out of my mind. Well done on getting past the mind trap I apparently had...

Comment: It would work, except that a Boa is not a type of Python. They are related in that they are from the same Order, but they are of different Genus (Boidae and Pythonidae respectively).

Comment: @jsm It seems Merriam-Webster has made a mistake then (perhaps OP used the same reference?)